# How to store all the output before multiprocessing finish?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to run multiprocess in python.
Here is an example:

```
def myFunction(name,age):
     output = paste(name,age)
     return output

names = ["A","B","C"]
ages = ["1","2","3"]

with mp.Pool(processes=no_cpus) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(myFunction,zip(names,ages))

results_table = pd.concat(results)
results_table.to_csv(file,sep="\t",index=False)
```

`myFunction` in the real case takes really long time. Sometime I have to interupt the running and start again. However the `results` will only be written to the output file when all `pool.starmap` is done. How can I store the intermediate/cache result before it's finished?
I don't want to change myFunction from `return` to `.to_csv()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `map`, use method [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=imap#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap), which returns an iterator that when iterated gives each result one by one as they become available (i.e. returned by `my_function`). However, the results must still be returned in order. If you do not care about the order, than use `imap_unordered`.

As each dataframe is returned and iterated, it is converted to a CSV file and outputted either with or without a header according to whether it is the first result being processed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def paste(name, age):
    return pd.DataFrame([[name, age]], columns=['Name', 'Age'])

def myFunction(t):
    name, age = t # unpack passed tuple
    output = paste(name, age)
    return output

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ["A","B","C"]
    ages = ["1","2","3"]

    no_cpus = min(len(names), mp.cpu_count())

    csv_file = 'test.txt'

    with mp.Pool(processes=no_cpus) as pool:
        # Results from imap must be iterated
        for index, result in enumerate(pool.imap(myFunction, zip(names,ages))):
            if index == 0:
                # First return value
                header = True
                open_flags = "w"
            else:
                header = False
                open_flags = "a"
            with open(csv_file, open_flags, newline='') as f:
                result.to_csv(f, sep="\t", index=False, header=header)
```

Output of *test.txt*:

```
Name    Age
A       1
B       2
C       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I got `imap` error of `missing 2 required positional arguments:`. I should mention I have several arguments.

Comment: "However I got ..." What?

Comment: I just now saw your updated comment. How am I supposed to respond to this if you don't provide more information or post your actual code or can't you now figure out what you need to do from reading the documentation on `imap`?  If your target worker function is an instance method of a class (e.g. `self.some_name`), then you need `self` as the first argument and, of course, the second argument would represent each element of the *iterable* being passed to `imap`, which was a `tuple` in the example above.

Comment: Hi thanks again for the reply. I now solved my problem after reading the starmap and imap. The reason why I didn't put my original codes is they're way two long and very specific, will be very confusing as well.

Comment: If my answer was the solution to your question then you should *accept* the answer.